# DATEDIF Calculation losing a minute

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have a timesheet for users to enter Start Time, End Time and Breaks.  I've created this calculation to total the number of minutes worked.  However, sometimes it loses a minute.  How do I fix this ?
Here's my code:

```
=(INT((EndDateTime-StartDateTime)*1440))-BreakMin
```

Here's an example of the calculation losing a minute:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all your requirements for calculating only minutes. But to show the time difference between two dates, you can use below formula which worked for me:

```
=TEXT([EndDateTime]-[StartDateTime],"h"" hrs ""m"" mins """)
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Hi Leapster, have you tried this solution? is it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could use this formula:

```
=ROUND((EndDateTime-StartDateTime)*1440,0)
```

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/round-function-b5e7cff8-5e61-4172-82f6-86308e403748